# Comparing a date variable in FoxPro commandline

Tags: foxpro

I would like to perform the following commands:

**////accept to x
////display all for date_field=x**

The purpose of these commands is to input a value x, after that I am going to display all the registers from a table whose date_field variable equals x
The date_field has a variable of type (Date,8)

These date variables are stored like this for example: 03/11/17, 04/23/17 and so on. From keyboard, I am typing for example 03/11/17. Then, I try to compare, I got errors. Could someone tell me the right set of commands to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it you are assigning a value that you have entered to a variable called 'x' and then using 'x' to compare against the date field.

The problem is probably that 'x' is a string and you are trying to compare it to a date. So you need to use the ctod() function. For example:

```
select * from mytable where date_field = ctod(x)
```

Also be careful as to what your regional settings are.

Answer (score 0):

When you say your are typing it in on the keyboard does that mean foxpro is prompting you?

You can set the input to receive a date object like this in your file.prg:

```
inputdate = {  /  /  }
@10,25 SAY "Enter Input Date: MM/DD/YYYY" GET inputdate
READ
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a date literal expression. In FoxPro, that is in the form {^yyyy/mm/dd}.

For instance, to compare to February 11 2018, use {^2018/2/11}

Answer (score 0):

> Comparing a date variable in FoxPro commandline
>
> accept to x
>
> display all for date_field=x

By "Command Line" I assume that you mean to use the Foxpro Command Window and enter single line commands.   If not, then you need to clarify what you are trying to do.

While in the FP Command window you type the following single lines one at a time:

```
x = {^2018/2/11}  && Assign this value to 'x' if you want the date February 11 2018
SELECT * FROM MyDataTable WHERE Date_Field = x INTO CURSOR Results READWRITE  && use SQL Query to get results from Data Table MyDataTable
SELECT Results   && go to results table/cursor
BROWSE     && make it visible on-screen
```

Since your question is so very general and basic, you might want to spend some time looking at the free, on-line VFP tutorial videos at:
[Free Online VFP Tutorial Videos](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)

Yes these videos are about Visual Foxpro rather than the OLD Foxpro, but there is quite a lot in common.

Good Luck